# How to mapping a WordPress MultiSite Network Subdirectories to new domain with all subsites

Tags: multisite

How I can mapping MU subdirectories like:

olddomain.com/subdirectory/subsite1
olddomain.com/subdirectory/subsite2
olddomain.com/subdirectory/subsite2

newdomain.com mapping ->

newdomain.com/subsite1
newdomain.com/subsite2
newdomain.com/subsite3

Answer (score 0):

On your olddomain.com, if you're using an apache server, add `.htaccess` rewrite similar to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /subdirectory/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1
```

This will take any `olddomain.com/subdirectory/{site_slug}/` requests and 301 redirect them to `newdomain.com/{site_slug}`